# 2 SQL Запроса, с самыми пожилыми продавцами. И Через покупателя других вывести имена других покупателей

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, запрос

1. По названию города(через параметрическое окно) вывести имена самых пожилых продавцов, проживающих в этом городе
2. По имени покупателя (через параметрическо окно) вывести именя других покупателей его магазинов.

```
SELECT s.Name, s.Years, c.City
FROM Sellers AS s, City AS c, Shops AS sh
WHERE (((s.Years) In (SELECT MAX(Years) FROM Sellers as s, City as c, Shops AS sh
WHERE s.CityID = c.CityID
AND City = город)) AND ((c.City)=[город]) AND ((c.CityID)=[s].[CityID]));
```

```
SELECT Name
FROM Buyers AS b, [Buyers shops] AS bs, Shops AS s
WHERE b.BuyersID = bs.BuyersID AND bs.ShopsID=s.ShopsID;
```

[image: Таблицы связей]

Comment: Вы думаете, что можно закинуть вопрос, не объяснив что у вас не работает? Ребус. Какой результат ждёте?

Comment: Первый запрос работает не правильно, а второй выдает пустую таблицу...

Answer (score 0):

Первая выборка продавцов по названию города с сортировкой по возрасту будет выглядеть так:

```
    select
      s.Name, s.Years, c.City
    from
      Sellers s
    left join
      City c
    on
     c.CityID = s.CityID
    where
     c.City = 'город'
    order by s.years desc -- если поле years означает возраст
--  order by s.years asc -- а если это год рождения то так
```

Вторая выборка, если я правильно понял условие, будет такой:

```
select
  b.Name
from
  Buyers b
left join
  ([Buyers shops] bs, Shops s)
on
  (bs.BuyersID = b.BuyersID and s.ShopsID = bs.ShopID )
where
  s.ShopsID in (
select 
  bs1.ShopID 
from 
  [Buyers shops] bs1
left join
  Buyers b1
on
  bs1.BuyersID = b1.BuyersID
where
  b1.name = 'имя покупателя'
 )
```

Comment: "Syntax Error JOIN Operation" вот такую ошибку пишет  во втором запросе.
А первый запрос выдает пустую таблицу и даже не спрашивает название города.